PA Cloud: List rows present in a table only returns rows filtered on the source Excel file?
A Power Automate Cloud using the "List rows present in a table" action was returning far fewer rows than it sould, despite having a high pagination value set up (even higher than the number of rows in the file) , and I have noticed it seems to be that if a filter is applied in the source Excel file in Sharepoint, the action only returns filtered ("visible") rows.
Copilot claims it is a feature, but I really do not think that it is working as expected (are users expected to manually remove all filters from the source file everytime an automated flow is triggered?). Particularly inconvenient considering it is a shared file to which several people might be applying different filters at the same time.
Is there a way to conveniently work around this? We also have a limited Office 365 license, so Office scripts or HTTP actions are not an option.
Cheers.
